# Sort users based on their maximum number of followers in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 tables one is for users(events in my case) and follows which is a join table to users and events,
I want to sort my events based on maximum no of followers they have
like i can get no of followers of a particular event using

```
@event.followers.count
```

but how can I execute a query to get an event with maximum no of followers

something like this =>

```
@mainevent = Event.includes(:follow).where(start: Time.now-1.days .. Time.now+1.days).order(' *followers_count* ').first
```

or

```
@mainevent = Event.find_by_sql( 'followers max using sql query' )
```

anything to give me event ordered by max no of followers

my Event.rb

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
 ....
 act_as_followable
belongs_to :club
belongs_to :amitian

 ....
```

end

my amitian.rb

```
class Amitian < ApplicationRecord
 ...
   act_as_follower
   has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
 ..
end
```

at some places i have used act_as_followable gem 
and at some places i have defined my own following model something like this

```
has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                                   foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                   dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :following, through: :active_relationships,  source: :followed
  has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
```

I want an ans that works for both cases

Comment: Can you show us the models with associations?

Comment: updated the associations

Comment: entire model is very big.. and useless for this q, will only mess up the readability .. so I am showing associations only

Comment: What is the relation between Event and Follow?

Comment: updated ... in case of event model i am using act_as_followable gem .. so follower_id: event and followed_id: amitian in follows model through has_many: through relation as shown in later case in code

Comment: Try `@mainevent = Event.includes(:follow).where(start: Time.now-1.days .. Time.now+1.days).order("count(follows.event_id) DESC").first`

Comment: whenever I use includes it throws an error  Can't join 'Event' to association named 'follows'; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: Try `@mainevent = Event.includes(:followers).where(start: Time.now-1.days .. Time.now+1.days).order("count(followers.event_id) DESC").first` instead

Comment: already tried.. same errir

Comment: I can't seem to understand ... @event.followers work but Event.includes(:followers) doesn't why..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might dip into raw SQL for something like this. Your tables I think have slightly different names.

```
Event.find_by_sql(<<SQL
  SELECT events.*, COUNT(events.id) AS total_followers
  FROM events
  INNER JOIN followers ON events.follower_id = followers.id
  GROUP BY followers.id
  ORDER BY total_followers DESC;
SQL).first
```

Comment: well, I had to edit your query a little bit .. but the idea of using SQL worked ... Thanks a lot